# Xcode preview not working

Tags: xcode, xcode8, render, scenekit

I created a sceneKit game project in Xcode. In the art.scnassests folder there's an included 3D model and texture. I can see the texture fine but the 3D model doesn't appear in the editor. I even added my own 3D models which the editor doesn't preview. I know they are there because if I run the app the model is in the app.

I tried restarting, create a new project, installing Xcode 8.3.3 instead of using 9.2 but I still can't get a preview. I need the preview for obvious reasons and also when I try to create a particle system the preview for this dent work either. (The preview does however work for the included texture.png)

Answer (score 0):

SceneKit Editor is not previewing your model because by default it doesn't have any texture set. You can assign the different channels of the texture or at least the diffuse attribute to preview your model. Thanks

[image]